# Finding an id from the given table by using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: web table]

How can I find "id" of above web table, if I only know  name of a particular customer. For example from the above table how can I find "CUSTOMER ID" of "THOMAS HANDY".

Comment: Please add the html of the table and the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for looks similar this (Note this is written in Ruby)

`if(tab['class'].include?(var))`

`tab` is a selector variable.

`var` would be what you want it to have.

So something like the following...

```
#Logic to Loop through each table - Parameterising it as table
if(table.text.include?('Thomas Hardy'))
  table['id']
end
#End of Loop Logic
```

Although as people have said, you're missing lots of info

Comment: All you need to do is adapt your java code from what I've written. So check if the `table['class']` includes the string `Thomas Hardy`

If it does, you want to return the parameter `table['id']`